# C# - Get status code for customErrors page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web.config file I have customErrors on and default redirect to my controller ErrorController like so:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/">
</customErrors>
```

What I am trying do now in my Index method of my ErrorController is get the error code (404, 405, etc), I have tried the following:

```
 public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.statusCode = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode;

        return View();
    }
}
```

But it always returns 200 because its redirecting to a page with the status code 200....When I goto a page that does not exists, I still get a 200 code instead of 404. I just want to have one page, get the error code instead of having multiple error pages. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `defaultRedirect` and use the `global.asax.cs`

Enter some code like this.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
        protected void Application_Error()
        {

             //prevent the errors coming back!
             this.Context.ClearError();

             //redirect
             this.Context.Response.Redirect($"~/Home/Error");

        }
```

The error code is probably in the `this.Context` somewhere use debug and try and find it.

Just an FYI `this.Context.AllErrors` has all the errors so can show you what went wrong.

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode; still returns 200 when it should be 404 as I am trying to goto a page that does not exists....could I get the status code from Application_Error and pass it to my Error Controller

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do. sorry didn't make that clear.